# How to find an empty cell in a row and return corresponding column header?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Using this data, I'm looking to write a formula that will return the Phase a client is currently in - i.e. the next consecutive phase that does NOT have an "X" in its column:

[image]

This is my desired outcome, where Phase will automatically update as phases are marked with an "X" in the above data sheet:

[image]

INDEX-MATCH seems useful here, but I'm not sure how to look for the next empty cell in a row (i.e. current phase) and how to return the Phase in the first row.

Comment: Do you just want the output `3`... you could just use `COUNTIFS`. Or do you want the actual header from the phase row?

Comment: Looking for the actual header. I've simplified the phases here for the purposes of the example - the actual phase titles used will be more detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following approach, using `INDEX/MATCH` and `COUNTIFS`:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,,1+COUNTIFS(INDEX($A$2:$E$5,MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$5,0),),"x"))
```

[image]